# Transparent Form Background

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to set backcolor to transparent by solution given at msdn but failed is there any way to make background transparent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Do you get an error?  What's happening when you try?  Have you tried just setting the form backcolor in the GDI?

Comment: it remains same control color.If i try to set opacity that fades the image that i am using I am trying to make a splash screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, set the form's TransparencyKey property.  Make the BackColor the same value.  You need to pick a color that won't appear anywhere else in the form.  Color.Fuchsia is a good choice, it's a fuchsed-up color.

This isn't a good idea for a splash screen.  The point of having one is that the user can see it.  The linked MSDN article is only appropriate for (some) child controls, not the form.

Comment: +1 for your accurate definition of Fuchsia. Also, I think what he meant is using a transparency to have a non-rectangular splash screen.